# Inferencing tflite model using cpp

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite, h5py

I am trying to infer my tflite model using cpp. I have trained the model and save h5 file. Now I'm trying to load it with cpp and get predictions. I tried the following set of codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/tools/gen_op_registration.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile("model.tflite");   //CHANGED

tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);

// Resize input tensors, if desired.
interpreter->AllocateTensors();

float* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0);
// Fill `input`.

interpreter->Invoke();

float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting an error as:

```
3   41  E:\kaino\TF\tf\app\main.cpp [Error] tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h: No such file or directory
```

Do I have to install a package or do I have to add another file? I'm new to this and please can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing includes directory to your compiler.
Basically you want to include the path where all files like "tensorflow/lite/..." are there, so the compiler can search this directory and find the required header files.

Example for GCC,

```
g++ main.cc -I /tmp/my_local_path
```

For more information https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options